# Eliminar salto de linea a un char *string

Tags: c

hay alguna forma de eliminar los '\n', en este ejemplo tal cual, se tiene el ****char *strings[]**** ? (asi lo necesito, dado que lo leí de un archivo) porque la salida que obtengo es Segmentation fault

```
   void choppy(char *s){
     s[strcspn ( s, "\n" )] = '\0';
   }

  int main(){

  char *strings[] = {"one\n","two\n","three\n", "four\n", "five\n"};
  char *name;

  for(int i =0; i < sizeof(strings)/ sizeof(strings[0]); i++){
    name = strings[i];
    choppy(strings[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Este ejemplo no te vale para hacer lo que deseas. Si quieres que te funcione el código deberás clonar el contenido de esas cadenas estáticas en una zona de memoria que permita modificaciones.

Comment: cómo lo clonaria?, por que en realidad no sería estático lo que leo de un archivo, supongamos que leí eso, y lo guardo en un array de string. Gracias por su respuesta

Comment: En mi respuesta he puesto un ejemplo con `strcpy()`.

Comment: Perfecto, mil gracias!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las cadenas estáticas que tienes dentro la siguiente línea se están generando en una zona de memoria que no permite modificaciones:

De modo que, para que tu prueba de concepto funcione adecuadamente, deberás copiarlas a una zona de memoria que sí lo permita:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void choppy(char *s)
{
  s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
  char *strings1[] = {"one\n", "two\n", "three\n", "four\n", "five\n"};
  char strings[5][50];

  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(strings) / sizeof(strings[0]); i++) {
    /* Hacemos una copia de la cadena en una zona de memoria que se pueda modificar */
    strcpy(strings[i], strings1[i]);
    choppy(strings[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

He usado una zona de memoria que aloja espacio para cinco líneas de un máximo de 50 caracteres. En su lugar podrías usar `malloc()` para alojar un número arbitrario de líneas y longitud de línea, recordando que luego debes liberar esa memoria con `free()`. He usado un alojamiento fijo para simplificar mi ejemplo.

**TL;DR**

Las cadenas definidas en el código se alojan en el mismo bloque de memoria que el ejecutable y éste se marca como solo lectura por el cargador del ejecutable (no se puede modificar) por lo que te generará un error de acceso denegado al intentar modificar algo de ese bloque de memoria.